# Tuleap Installation Error

Tags: web, installation, centos, tuleap

I have installed Tuleap following the documentation on CentOS release 6.10 (Final). 
(2.6.32-754.3.5.e16.x86_64 )
On a VM through VMware.
I gave the domain name 192.168.30.222.

I am unable to reach it through the browser. Timed out.
I am able to ping.
Ports 80, 443, 22 are open.
I am able to SSH into the server, but its logging into root.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm. Got it working. I had not installed the expected dependencies in it. Like php.